# MAC Address and ColdFire MFC5329

Tags: ethernet, mac, freescale

I am working with the ColdFire MCF5329. I have worked on other projects where the Ethernet function was a separate chip, namely, SMC. The SMC Ethernet chip has pins out for a 64 byte EEProm to store the MAC address.

Where does one store the MAC address when the Ethernet chip is integrated, as in the case of the ColdFire MCF5329 and when there appears to be no separate pins outs for a small EEProm?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you meant MCF5329 (not MFC5329)

According to the [MCF5329 data sheet](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/data_sheet/MCF5329DS.pdf), there are both an SSI (synchronous serial interface) and an I2C module, either of which could be used to access a small external EEPROM.

If you do not already have a block of MAC addresses (or if you do not wish to go to the trouble of programming the EEPROM), Microchip offers I2C EEPROMs with pre-programmed EUI-48 or EUI-64 addresses: 
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002124E.pdf

MAC addresses are sometimes stored in a reserved location in non-volatile program memory (such as FLASH memory). Since the MCF5329 has no internal non-volatile memory, you will need to look to where the program memory is stored to see if this is an option. If you go this route, take care that any bootloader or other form of software/firmware update will not overwrite the MAC address.

Some microcontrollers even have a small section of OTP (one-time programmable) memory for uses such as this, although it appears that the MCF5329 does not.

Comment: You can also use [locally administered MAC addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Address_details). That gives you 46 effective address bits (an ordinary MAC's 48 bits of address space minus one bit for the globally unique flag and one bit for the multicast flag) which you can assign in any manner you like. It wouldn't be acceptable for a production run, but for development and testing it should work just fine.